# How to tell if a Firestore operation succeeded or failed?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I need to be able to tell if a set(), delete(), or update() operation on a document has succeeded before I do a transaction operation to increment or decrement a counter.

I've tried to print what set(), delete() and update() return, but it always just returns "seconds" and "nanos" whether or not the operation succeeded or not. I've tried to do operations on document IDs that don't exist, or collections that don't exist, but it always just returns the same thing with no indication if it did anything or not.

```
collection.("some_col").document("SoM3DoC").delete()
collection.("some_other_col").document("SoM30tH3RDoC").collection("some_col_ref").document("SoM3DoC").delete()
```

Then, ONLY if the above succeeded (the document existed and was deleted):

```
some_transaction(transaction, collection.("some_other_col").document("SoM30tH3RDoC")) # decrement a counter in this doc
```

I'm expecting that the operation methods would either throw an error if it couldn't complete the operation or return some message to indicate it but I can't seem to get any response. I even tried starting with some random collection like `collection.("asdfsergreasg").document...` but there's still no response.

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/index.html) indicates what to expect from various operations, so you should use that as a reference.  Some operations on documents and collections that don't exist don't yield errors.  Some do.  For example, calling `get` on a document that doesn't exist isn't an error, but the returned object will be clear that no document exists.  However, calling `update` on a document that doesn't exist should raise an error.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link! I checked the doc for delete() and am very surprised:
Returns: "The time that the delete request was received by the server. If the document did not exist when the delete was sent (i.e. nothing was deleted), this method will still succeed and will still return the time that the request was received by the server."

How am I supposed to complete other operations that depend on the delete() method succeeding? I don't want to have to perform multiple get()s every time.

Comment: What delete is telling you is that there is currently no document for the given reference.  It was either deleted, or it never existed.  If you need to know if the named document was actually deleted, you need to use a transaction so you can atomically know for sure that you're dealing with something that exists.